# Choosing applicants for positions via a MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL tables. They represent CS courses at a school and applicants to be a TA (teaching assistant) for specific courses.

I want to create a query that will print the "best" applicant for each course. The constraints for the best applicant are:

1. Applicants with `Applicants.level` = 7 are matched first.
2. Applicants with `ApplicantsToCourses.returning` = true are chosen second.
3. All other applicants are matched without further discrimination.

The table definitions are:

```
CREATE TABLE Courses (
 course_number SMALLINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 course_section SMALLINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 instructor CHAR(30),
 lab_time CHAR(30),
 PRIMARY KEY(course_number, section),
 FOREIGN KEY(course_number, section) REFERENCES ApplicantsToCourses(course_number, course_section)
)

CREATE TABLE Applicants (
 student_id CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
 name CHAR(30),
 email CHAR(30),
 gpa DECIMAL(4,3) UNSIGNED,
 level CHAR(2),
 timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY(student_id),
 FOREIGN KEY(student_id) REFERENCES ApplicantsToCourses(student_id),
 CHECK(gpa <= 4.000)
)

CREATE TABLE ApplicantsToCourses (
 student_id CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
 returning BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL,
 course_number SMALLINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 course_section SMALLINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(student_id, course_number, course_section),
 FOREIGN KEY(student_id) REFERENCES Applicants(student_id),
 FOREIGN KEY(course_number, course_section) REFERENCES Courses(course_number, course_section)
)
```

My attempt at a query was . . .

```
select a.student_id, ac.course_number, ac.course_section
from Applicants a, ApplicantsToCourses ac, Courses c
where a.student_id = ac.student_id and ac.course_number = c.course_number and ac.course_section = c.course_section
order by a.level, ac.returning desc
```

. . . but that certainly doesn't have the correct logic.

Comment: Is this a homework question? In what way is your query incorrect? What's wrong with the results it shows?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following pseudo code to create some temporary tables that should help you reach your final solution.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  Applicants APP
JOIN  ApplicantsToCourses ATC ON ATC.student_id = APP.student_id
JOIN  Courses COU ON COU.number = ATC.course_number AND COU.section = ATC.course_section
WHERE APP.level = 7

SELECT * 
FROM  Applicants APP
JOIN  ApplicantsToCourses ATC ON ATC.student_id = APP.student_id
JOIN  Courses COU ON COU.number = ATC.course_number AND COU.section = ATC.course_section
WHERE ATC.returning = true
```